# How to show the limit does not exist.

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to0}\frac{1}{n}$$

How do I show that the limit does not exist?

I did $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to 0^+}=\infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to0^-}=-\infty$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to0^+}\neq \lim_{n\to0^-}$

Thus $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to0}\frac{1}{n}$ does not exist. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Really, even $\lim_{n\to0+} \frac1n=\infty$ is already a way of saying that the limit doesn't exist. It just fails to exist in a specific and useful way, which is why we use the $\infty$ notation.

Comment: @GregMartin According to other notation we say that $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac1{x^2}$ exists finite,  $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x^2}$ exists infinite and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x}$ doesn't exist. It seems that the asker is referring to this way to indicate existence.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for extended real line where $\infty $ is included.

Then as, $\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{1}{x} \to \infty $ and $\lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{1}{x} \to -\infty $ ,

So,from these , you can conclude that the limit doesn't exist even in extended real line $\mathbb{R} ∪ \{\infty\} $

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the analysis of the other responses.  However, I
would instead have taken a (very basic) $\epsilon, \delta$ approach
of proof by contradiction.

Suppose the limit exists, and let $L$ = this limit. 
Without loss of generality, assume that $L \geq 0.$ 
That is, the proof for $L < 0$ would be very similar.

Then, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there must exist a $\delta > 0$
such that $|L - \frac{1}{n}| < \epsilon$ whenever
$0 < |(n - 0)| < \delta$.

Choose $\epsilon = (1/2).$ 
Then supposedly, a *satisfying* $\delta$ can be found
that corresponds to $\epsilon = (1/2).$

It now remains to show that **no matter how small** you make $\delta$,
it will **not satisfy** the requirement for $\epsilon = (1/2).$

Choose $M \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that both of the following are true:
(1) $M > L + 1$ 
(2) $(1/M) < \delta.$

Let $N = (1/M).$ 
Then $0 < |(N - 0)| < \delta$ and 
$|L - \frac{1}{N}| = |L - M| > 1 > \epsilon.$

With $\epsilon$ fixed at $\epsilon = (1/2)$ 
the above analysis shows that no matter how small you choose $\delta,$
a positive integer $M$ can be found, and $N$ can be set to $(1/M)$ in
such a way as to prove that $\delta$ does not satisfy $\epsilon = (1/2).$

Therefore, with $\epsilon = (1/2)$ 
**no satisfying** $\delta$ can be found.

This contradicts the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of convergence.
Therefore, the limit **does not exist.**

Answer (score 1):

Your final answer is correct but the way to prove it depends upon the definition you are adopting for the "*limit existence*".

In some contexts, the definition adopted is that limit at a point exists when right and left limit are equal and its value is a real number. According to this definition, it suffices to observe that

$$\lim_{n\to 0^+}\frac1n=\infty$$

to conclude that limit doesn't exist.

A different definition assumes that limit exists when  right and left limit are equal and its value is a real number or it diverges at positive infinite or it diverges at negative infinite. According to this other definition, we need to observe that

$$\lim_{n\to 0^+}\frac1n=\infty \neq \lim_{n\to 0^-}\frac1n=-\infty$$

to conclude that limit at $n=0$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for proving not existing a limit it will be enough to make a sequence example that the limits converges for that. For instance you can say: $n = a_m = \frac{1}{m}$. So since $\lim_{m \to \infty} m = \infty$ so the limit does not exist.
By the way your provement is correct.