# Inexistence or limit that does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

We suppose that have this limit:

$$\lim _{x\to +\infty }\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}$$

> Are there theorems in Mathematical Analysis, corollaries that use successions, particular strategies, that help me to demonstrate that a limit exists or does not exist?

**Related question**: [Limits that do not exist: search of general techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813105/limits-that-do-not-exist-search-of-general-techniques)

Comment: When $x>4$, $\sqrt x>2$

Comment: This limit is $+\infty$, why do you ask for non existence?

Comment: @saulspatz Please can you put a solution?

Comment: @enzotib Then the answer is not correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812138/verification-for-a-series-of-limits

Comment: @Sebastiano that answer states that the limit does not exist _finitely_, but I say that the limit is $\infty$, in fact $$
\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt{x}}}{x-2}=
\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt{x}}}{x-1}\cdot\frac{x-1}{x-2}=
(x-1)^{\sqrt{x}-1}\cdot\frac{x-1}{x-2}\to\infty^\infty\cdot1
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{(x-1)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}\ge \frac{(x-2)^{\sqrt x}}{x-2}=(x-2)^{\sqrt x-1}\to \infty$$

since it is in the form $\infty^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer as usual 

Comment: You are very welcome! Bye

Comment: Wait...please :-) then...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812138/verification-for-a-series-of-limits this answer is not correct? :-(

Comment: But is there a general technique, without using upper or low bound, to show that a limit does not exist?

Comment: @Sebastiano The limit diverges to $\infty$.  Usually, when we say that a limit exists, we exclude the values $\pm\infty$  Both answers are correct, but use somewhat different terminology.

Comment: @saulspatz Then I have not understood. Can you explain easily your comment with an answer(very very simple language because I am not native speaker)?

Comment: @Sebastiano I'm sorry, but I don't know what else to say.  Perhaps you should post a question explaining your difficulty in more detail.

Comment: @saulspatz My difficulty is to understood if a limit not exist or exist and if there are particular tecniques: sequences, lim sup, lim min, or other mathematical methods. My question exist: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813105/limits-that-do-not-exist-search-of-general-techniques

Comment: @Sebastiano Refer also to [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2907164/505767) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3795934/505767).